# Unlock iphone and run app triggered by the starting and stopping of charging

Tags: ios, iphone

This is a bit of an odd one.

I am very new to iPhone programming and more interested in how doable/possible this is.

What I want is to have my old iPhone connected to the power and once I remove the electricity (stop it charging) the screen unlocks and displays a counter app, just a simple seconds/minutes/hours counter. 
During the counting the screen would stay on.

Then when the power returns (it starts charging again) the timer is reset and the screen is allowed to be turned off (phone can lock itself as it usually does after a period of inactivity).

Comment: Almost all of that is possible but you can't manipulate the way your iPhone works when you unplug it from the charger. So you can't say unlock when I unplug you. And you can't unlock your device from code. That's all not part of your app. iOS handles that.

Comment: Would some equivalent of rooting for ios help? Would having the right permissions not allow us that level of control?

Comment: I am not sure. If you jailbreak your device you could eventually do this but I don't see why you would want that and don't recommend it.

Comment: it's an old and unused iphone, I am not too worried about it. Thanks for the info, I'll keep researching.

Answer (score 0):

On android, this would be possible, as there are little to no limitations. Apple do not like people to use some (most) of system's features, so therefore; even if you did manage to get it to work- it would be rejected immediately.

Comment: It doesn't seem that this an app @TheFooBarWhy wants to submit to the AppStore

Answer (score -1):

There's no possibility to program something whenever you unplug your phone. 
In other words; there's nothing on the iOS SDK that offers such functionality to allow code something when phone is unplugged.

Comment: But the phone knows to prompt the user once it is plugged in. It shows the little "charging" icon so it does know when power is available.

Comment: @Eric Garcia That's not right. You can access different states of the device. By checking these states you know if it is unplugged or charging. You could check that in a time interval or so.

Comment: time interval doesn't work in background... iOS kill that time interval thread

Comment: Not in the background. I mean if the app is open you could determine if the device is charging or not and so on. But you would have to check that every second or maybe every minute. That's what I meant.